# Fastest method to reformat terabytes of data

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have 100s of files that are 10s of Gbyte each. I need to reformat the files and combine to a more usable table format so I can group, sum, average, etc. the data. Reformatting the data using Python would take over a week. Even after I reformat it to a table I don't know if it would be too large for dataframe, but one problem at a time.

Can anyone suggest a faster method to reformat the text files? I'll consider anything C++, perl, etc.

### Sample data:

```
Scenario:  Modeling_5305 (0.0001)

Position:  NORTHERN UTILITIES SR NT,

"  ","THEO/Effective Duration","THEO/Yield","THEO/Implied Spread","THEO/Value","THEO/Price","THEO/Outstanding Balance","THEO/Effective Convexity","ID","WAL","Type","Maturity Date","Coupon Rate","POS/Position Units","POS/Portfolio","POS/User Defined 1","POS/SE Cash 1","User Defined 2","CMO WAL","Spread Over Yield",

"2017/12/31",16.0137 T,4.4194 % SEMI 30/360,0.4980 % SEMI 30/360,"6,934,452.0000 USD","6,884,052.0000 USD","7,000,000.0000 USD",371.6160 T,CachedFilterPartitions-PL_SPLITTER.2:665876C#3,29.8548 T,Fixed Rate Bond,2047/11/01,4.3200 % SEMI 30/360,"70,000.0000",All Portfolios,030421000,0.0000 USD,FRB,N/A,0.4980 % SEMI 30/360,

"2018/01/12",15.5666 T,4.8499 % SEMI 30/360,0.4980 % SEMI 30/360,"6,477,803.7492 USD","6,418,163.7492 USD","7,000,000.0000 USD",356.9428 T,CachedFilterPartitions-PL_SPLITTER.2:665876C#3,29.8219 T,Fixed Rate Bond,2047/11/01,4.3200 % SEMI 30/360,"70,000.0000",All Portfolios,030421000,0.0000 USD,FRB,N/A,0.4980 % SEMI 30/360,

Scenario:  Modeling_5305 (0.0001)

Position:  OLIVIA ISSUER TR SER A (A,

"  ","THEO/Effective Duration","THEO/Yield","THEO/Implied Spread","THEO/Value","THEO/Price","THEO/Outstanding Balance","THEO/Effective Convexity","ID","WAL","Type","Maturity Date","Coupon Rate","POS/Position Units","POS/Portfolio","POS/User Defined 1","POS/SE Cash 1","User Defined 2","CMO WAL","Spread Over Yield",

"2017/12/31",1.3160 T,19.0762 % SEMI 30/360,0.2990 % SEMI 30/360,"3,862,500.0000 USD","3,862,500.0000 USD","5,000,000.0000 USD",2.3811 T,CachedFilterPartitions-PL_SPLITTER.2:681071AA4,1.3288 T,Interest Rate Index Linked Note,2019/05/30,0.0000 % MON 30/360,"50,000.0000",All Portfolios,010421002,0.0000 USD,IRLIN,N/A,0.2990 % SEMI 30/360,

"2018/01/12",1.2766 T,21.9196 % SEMI 30/360,0.2990 % SEMI 30/360,"3,815,391.3467 USD","3,815,391.3467 USD","5,000,000.0000 USD",2.2565 T,CachedFilterPartitions-PL_SPLITTER.2:681071AA4,1.2959 T,Interest Rate Index Linked Note,2019/05/30,0.0000 % MON 30/360,"50,000.0000",All Portfolios,010421002,0.0000 USD,IRLIN,N/A,0.2990 % SEMI 30/360,
```

### I'd like to reformat to this csv table so I can import to dataframe:

```
Position, Scenario, TimeSteps, THEO/Value

NORTHERN UTILITIES SR NT, Modeling_5305, 2018/01/12, 6477803.7492

OLIVIA ISSUER TR SER A (A, Modeling_5305, 2018/01/12, 3815391.3467
```

Comment: In my experience the biggest bottleneck is the library you use to access / manipulate csv or other file formats. What library do you use? Have you tried other libraries? Why won't a simple bash script do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

There are two big bottlenecks when you have to manipulate large files or a great number of files. One is your file system, which is limited by either your HDD or SSD (your storage medium), the connection to the storage medium and your operation system. Usually you can not change that. But you have to ask yourself, what is my top speed? How fast can the system read and write? You can never be faster than that.
A rough estimation of the maximum speed would be the time you need to read all your data plus the time you need to write all your data.

The other bottleneck is the library you use in order to make the changes. Not all Python packages are created equal, there are huge speed differences. I recommend to try several approaches on a small test sample until you find one that works for you.

Keep in mind that most file systems like to either read or write huge junks of data. So you should try to avoid situation where you alternate between reading one line and then writing one line. In other words not only the library is important but how you use it.

Different programming languages, while they might provide a good library for this task and can be a good idear, will not speed up the process in any meaningful way (so you won't get 10 times the speed or anything).

Comment: Data is sitting on network file storage with gigabit connection. I can move it to a server that's on a 10Gb ring connection to the file storage. I was trying with "open" file and going through line by line. Also tried perl but that's also going through line by line single thread. Do you have suggestion what batch method or multi-thread process is available? I did notice when I moved from Python 2.7 to 3.5 my conversion programs using "open" command got significantly slower (about 5x slower in i/o). 3.6 was slightly faster but nowhere near 2.7 was.

Comment: Once again, the version of python or the programming language in general has nothing to do with the speed. You have to find out how to read huge junks of data and store them in a buffer before writing them back in bulk. That you read line-by-line in python does not mean that the package you use is reading line by line.

Comment: Also, what packages do you use for python? Especially some of the CSV packages are dreadfully slow.

Comment: I'm not importing any packages other than sys and pandas. Using open(file,'r') to open file and open(file,'w',  newline = '\r\n') to write to. Writing is done in large chunks. Use "for line in file:" to go through line by line.

Comment: Try using pylint on your code and open a new question if you know where your bottleneck is. Alternatively seek a package that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use C/C++ with memory mapping.

With memory mapping you can go through the data as if it were one big array of bytes (and this will also prevent a copy of the data from kernel space to user space (on Windows, not sure about Linux)).

For very large files you could map one block at a time (for example 10GB).

For writing, use a buffer (say 1MB) to store the results, and then write that buffer to the file each time (using `fwrite()`).

Whatever you do, do not use streaming I/O or `readline()`.

The process should take no longer (or at least not much longer) than the time it would take to copy the files on disk (or over network since you're using network file storage).

If you have the option, write the data to a different (physical) disk than the one you are reading from.

Comment: This would be awesome. I'll try it out once I figure out how to do memory mapping. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Sung Are you programming for Windows or Linux?

Comment: I usually build and test in Windows then move it to a linux server.